# Jolt trans form - remove whitespaces

Tags: json, jolt

How can we remove leading or trailing whitespaces from a value? using Jolt transform script

**Example Input**

```
{
  "parent": {
    "rating": {
      **"value": "Good            "**
    }
  }
}
```

**Spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parent": {
        "rating": {
          "value": "Rating"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output :**

```
{
  "Rating" : "Good            "
}
```

**this is what needed**

```
{
  "Rating" : "Good"
}
```

Comment: Input is : {
  "parent": {
    "rating": {
      "value": "Good            "
    }
  }
}

Comment: There isn't a function that removes / squashes white space in Jolt

Comment: There's a `=trim` function available.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `=trim` function in `modify-overwrite-beta` operation:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parent": {
        "rating": {
          "value": "Rating"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Rating": "=trim"
    }
  }
]
```